# How old is Neelix?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, age

The Talaxian named Neelix is one of the main characters in Star Trek Voyager:

[image]

His duties on board the ship range from chef, to ambassador and ship's moral officer. Also, through-out the seasons we get to know a lot about his interests (mainly throwing parties, cooking and hooking up with [alien babes](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Neelix#Romance)...), his family, his planet etc, but we never learn his age, something a tad strange as actually in one episode he was preoccupied with Tuvok's age!

Out of universe, his Memory Alpha [biography](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Neelix) doesn't seem to mention his age and I don't remember any of the producers discussing this (but I could be wrong).

So my question is: **Do we know how old Neelix is?**

Both canon and EU sources/quotes will be accepted.

Comment: at least fifteen (given he was present for the events at rinax in 2356) though i suspect significantly older. also shouldn't that really say alien babies?

Comment: @Ummdustry Perhaps, if you consider Kes ;) Otherwise, it's correct as it is.

Comment: Memory-Beta (referencing various EU novels) gives his birthdate as 2337

Comment: @Valorum If there was a specific quote from one of the books I could accept it as an answer.

Comment: *Pathways* by Jeri Taylor covers Neelix's childhood and early experiences up to meeting Voyager. It's probably in there somewhere... I just bought an ebook copy but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: I remember he got real old, real quickly like, during *Voyager's* run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Memory Beta article about Neelix](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Neelix):

> Neelix was born in 2337 on Rinax in the Delta Quadrant's Talax system, a son of Eximar and Axa. Following the slaughter of his entire family by the Haakonians in 2355, Neelix became a spacegoing trader until a fortunate encounter with Voyager in 2371, which saw him become guide, cook and morale officer, and "ambassador" for the Federation starship. Neelix remained aboard until 2377, when he joined with a group of Talaxians thousands of light-years away from Talax. (VOY episode & novelization: Caretaker; VOY episodes: "Parallax", "Jetrel", "Homestead"; VOY novel: Pathways)

So, when he joined Voyager in 2371, he was 34 years old.

Comment: And what is their source? (Like, quote from the original novel?)

Comment: As was discussed in above comments, it is mentioned in Pathways (which I have unfortunately not yet read). Just seen the question and remember having read this when I checked up on Neelix recently.